# How to put data to spinner on another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

How can I to put data to spinner which is on another layout?

I am newby on android, and now I have problem with spinners.
I have data at first class with his layout. And I want to put that data to other spinner which is on another layout. What I need to do? Create new Class or What? 
Please help! :)

Data is- Array

Answer (score 0):

You should put your data where it is accessible from everywhere.
so please put your data in **database** using SQLite or ORMs that help you work with Native database like SugarORM, ORMLite and Realm.
another way is to apply **singleton** pattern to store your data in a different class.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have an Array
Then make Array static

```
eg:- public static ArrayList<> new_array = new ArrayList<>;
```

now call this array any where in the activity
you will get data

Answer (score 0):

there is many to manage array data.
- create arraylist and use that data anywhere in the activity.
- using database also you can user.
- using Read & writing arrays of Parcelable objects
- using global application class ....etc